# MetaPost: mpost and plain.mp

Tags: macros, packages, metapost, primitives

- Am I right that 'pure' MetaPost (`mpost`), without `plain.mp`, knows only primitive commands? So that MetaPost compiler + `plain.mp` is like a pure TeX + PlainTeX or TeX + any other macros package?
- Is it possible to use 'pure' MetaPost, without any predefined macros? Or `mpost` itself needs `plain.mp` and without this file it won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can run MetaPost without any kind of format by running `mpost -ini` (basically iniMetaPost), but similar to iniTeX, it is not designed to be used directly and only intended to create new formats.

Comment: Thank you, understood. I've tried to compile my .mp file with ```mpost -ini``` and there were a lot of errors -- everything is undefined. Even 'usual' ```beginfig(1)``` and ```endfig``` are predefined macros. Yes, it is almost impossible to use a pure compiler without any macro packages...